# Deploying cloud foundry with BOSH - what does a "bosh delete deployment" clean up?

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

We've just gone through the process of deploying a multi node (34 nodes) cloud foundry using BOSH, with a few hiccups along the way.  One in particular was that it took us several "bosh deploy" runs to get through the initial compilation steps.  We'd start the bosh deploy, it would start compiling, get through a few components and then fail.  There is no doubt that we have some configuration issues with our VMWare based infrastructure and I suspect we are running out of resources.  But here is my main question for now.

We were able to get through the compiles by issuing a "bosh delete deployment ourcloud --force" after a failure.

What does this command clear out?  It obviously left successfully compiled stuff in place, but what is cleaned? Temporary storage? Anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is a good candidate for the bosh user's group, https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/bosh-users

Answer (score 1):

bosh delete deployment will delete an entire deployment, it deletes the VMs in the vcenter, clears it's db of the info and deletes the manifest. after it's done there should be no trace (except logs) of the deployment.

Comment: But the compilations that have been done to that point are NOT cleared away.  Arguably those compilations are a part of the deployment but they are retained through a "bosh delete deployment."  Where?  Is there anything else that is retained?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. No compilations should be retained because all VMs are being deleted. Also all the data regarding the deployment is being erased from the db. If you however are seeing compilations being retained, it would be a good idea to bring it up in https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/bosh-users  

Also the CPI you are using might have a bug. I would mention in the google groups what type of CPI are you using (i.e. AWS, vSphere or etc)